# R Fluidrow/Column Font Size

Tags: r, shiny

I want to increase the size of the font in a column, under fluid-row. Below is the code I am trying :

```
fluidRow(  
column(12, div(style="height:20px;font-size: 35px;"),'Approval Request Summary'))
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it almost right. You just need to make sure that the text to be rendered is within the call to `div()` rather than outside it (which is where you currently have it).

The following should give you the results you're expecting:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               div(style = "height:20px; font-size:35px;",
                   'Approval Request Summary'))
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```